# Equal height flex columns ruined by child element with display: flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

CSS:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
body > header {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #373737;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
aside {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #484848;
  font-size: 18px "SL";
  margin-top: 60px;
}
aside > ul.side-menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 100%;
}
aside > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "SL";
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #8E8E8E;
  transition: 300ms;
}
aside > ul > li > a.active {
  color: white;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>

  <header>

  </header>

  <aside>
    <ul class="side-menu">
      <li><a href="#" class="active">123</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
</body>
```

Codepan:

https://codepen.io/UADev/pen/zzmdPG

When you're opening fullscreen, this is what's happening:

[image]

Tried to use `height: 100%` on `body` and `html` elements, but it doesn't work correctly when you have another `flex` element with `flex-wrap: wrap` inside one of the `flex-child` elements like `aside` or `section` that follows immediately after `body`. I tried to remove `display:flex` from one of those elements and  it's broke the layout, but problem disappeared.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `min-height: 100vh` to the parent (`body`) and the default value `align-items: stretch` will cause the children to to fill the height of the parent.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
body > header {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #373737;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
aside {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #484848;
  font-size: 18px "SL";
  margin-top: 60px;
}
aside > ul.side-menu {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 100%;
}
aside > ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "SL";
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  color: #CCCCCC;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #8E8E8E;
  transition: 300ms;
}
aside > ul > li > a.active {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <header>

  </header>

  <aside>
    <ul class="side-menu">
      <li><a href="#" class="active">123</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">123</a></li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
</body>
```

Comment: min-height: 100vh; Resolved the problem. I cleaned my example (you can update the code in answer, so it woun't be confusing for others. I'm sorry that i updated it after you answered). Please, can you explain a little more ?

Comment: @Src what part don't you understand? `body` doesn't expand the height of the window by default, even though the `background-color` on `body` will. So `aside` will only be as tall as the parent, and the parent isn't the height of the viewport. Making body at least the height of the viewport (`min-height: 100vh`) makes it, well... at least the height of the viewport. So now the `aside` will stretch (because of `align-items: stretch` - the default) to fill the parent.

Comment: Ok, got it. I never used `vh` before and also tried to use 100% height on body, so that's why i was wondering.. Thank you once more)

Comment: @Src ah cool, yeah `100vh` works a lot better than `100%`. To make `body { height: 100%; }` work, you also have to add `height: 100%` to `html`

Comment: I tried to use 100% height on body and html elements before, but problem was still remaining when i had a `flex` container with `flex-wrap: wrap` inside one of the `flex-child` elements like `aside` or `section` in my example. But `100hv` handeled this problem just OK.

Comment: Just did some advanced testing and turns out that the problem not completely gone. Look what's happened when i scaled down the browser window: http://i65.tinypic.com/v4yq8y.jpg . But it is probably the topic for another question)

Comment: My bad, seems like i was using `heigh` instead of `min-height`. Sorry, my bad)